# Limit of a sequence. Let $ { \{a_n \}} $ be a sequence of real numbers. Then $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n $ exists if and only if

Tags: sequences-and-series, limits, limits-without-lhopital

Let $ { \{a_n \}} $ be a sequence of real numbers. Then $ \lim_{n \to \infty} a_n $ exists if and only if

(A) $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{2n}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{2n+2}$ exists

(B) $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{2n}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{2n+1}$ exists

(C) $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{2n}$ , $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{2n+1}$ and $\lim_{n \to \infty} a_{3n}$ exists

(D) none of the above

So there is IFF condition. So for one of the option to be true the vice versa has to be true. I've considered many sequences like sequence of even numbers or $\{-1^n\} $ sequence. But still not getting any satisfactory answer. Would really appreciate if someone can help me understand the intuition.

PS: I've asked this question before. But has been deleted by the Community bot as it had 0 votes and 30 days older. I'm really looking for an answer. Hope this time someone can answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The correct answer is (C), not (D).

Assume that $L_0=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n}$, $L_1=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{2n+1}$, and $L_2=\lim_{n\to\infty}a_{3n}$ exist. The sequence $\langle a_{6n}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a subsequence of both $\langle a_{2n}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\langle a_{3n}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, so it converges to both $L_0$ and $L_2$, which must therefore be equal. The sequence $\langle a_{6n+3}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ is a subsequence of both $\langle a_{2n+1}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ and $\langle a_{3n}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$, so it converges to both $L_1$ and $L_2$, which must therefore be equal. In other words, $L_0=L_1=L_2$, and I’ll simply call it $L$ henceforth.

Let $\epsilon>0$. The sequence $\langle a_{2n}:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $L$ so there is an $m_0\in\Bbb N$ such that $|a_{2n}-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge m_0$. Similarly, there is an $m_1\in\Bbb N$ such that $|a_{2n+1}-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge m_1$. Let $m=\max\{2m_0,2m_1+1\}$; if $n\ge m$ is even, then $\frac{m}2\ge m_0$, so $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$, and if $n$ is odd, then $\frac{n-1}2\ge m_1$, and again $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$. Thus, $|a_n-L|<\epsilon$ for all $n\ge m$, and since $\epsilon>0$ was arbitrary, we’ve shown that $\langle a_n:n\in\Bbb N\rangle$ converges to $L$.

Comment: Assuming that it was for the typo $a_{6n+1}$ (instead of the correct $a_{6n+3}$), this is a perfect example of a useless downvote: it’s sheer luck that I happened to notice it. A comment pointing out the typo would have ensured that it was brought to my attention.

Comment: Thanks for such a beautiful explaination I got the the first part. The 2nd part I'm finding difficult to understand. And seriously there are some serious trollers who downvote uselessly. I asked this same question before once. Someone closed it saying off topic!!

Comment: The other way around is easy. If $\lim a_n$ exists, then the limits of all subsequences exist and are equal to that limit.

Comment: @NS: You’re welcome! Don’t let yourself be overwhelmed by the technical details of the second part. The idea is simple: if all of the even-numbered terms from some point on are in $(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$, and all of the odd-numbered terms from some point on are also in $(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$, then if you go out far enough in the sequence **all** terms will from that point on will be in $(L-\epsilon,L+\epsilon)$.

Comment: @marty: I’m not sure, but I think that by ‘2nd part’ the OP meant my second paragraph, not the easy converse.

Comment: Thanks so much. Cant believe such stalwarts replied me. :) @BrianM.Scott

Comment: @NS: You’re very welcome. :-)

Answer (score 1):

For C,
suppose
$\lim a_{2n} = p$,
$\lim a_{2n+1} = q$,
$\lim a_{3n} = r$.

Considering
$a_{6n}$,
$p = r$.

Considering
$a_{6n+3}
=a_{2(3n+1)+1}$,
$q = r$.

Therefore $p = q = r$.

Since $a_{2n}$ and
$a_{2n+1}$
include all integers,
$\lim a_n$
exists.

So C is true.

Comment: Thanks. But this is the only half part. How to prove it vice versa??

Comment: The other way around is easy. If $\lim a_n$ exists, then the limits of all subsequences exist and are equal to that limit.

Answer (score 0):

By hint 1 the "only if"-statement is true in A, B and C. Since we do not know, that the limits are the same, all the "if"-statements are false, so statement D is correct.

Observations:
1. Even if the both limits in A coincide, we cannot conclude that lim a(n) converges. Counterexample: a(n)=1 if n is odd and a(n)=2 if n is even. Here both a(2n) and a(2n+2) have the same limit =2. But a(n) does not converge since there are two different accumulation points.
2. By hint 2, B and C are true if the all limits coincide.

Comment: In fact (C) is correct: if all three of those subsequences converge, one can prove that they have the same limit. See my answer.